# JavaScript prototype: filter->if(which function?)->map

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, prototype

I am studying react. I am struggling to use JavaScript prototype. What I want to do is below.

1. If `searchWord` is typed, filter the array(`props.rows`) to one containing the word.
2. If the number of elements has more than `rowsPerPage`, only `rowsPerPage` are displayed.

However, what I typed worked reversely like this.
Slice elements in `rowsPerPage`, and then filter elements containing `searchWord`.

I don't know which function is needed. Please help me. Thank you in advance.

(If it is possible to write code using only prototype, I want to do.)

(+ I edited code to trim it.)

```js
// reversed sequence
{(rowsPerPage > 0
? props.rows.slice(page * rowsPerPage, page * rowsPerPage + rowsPerPage)
: props.rows
)
.filter((row) =>
!searchWord.length || row.name
  .toString()
  .includes(searchWord.toString()) 
)
.map((item) => (
  <Hello />
))}
```

```js
// what I tried
{props.rows
.filter((row) =>
  !searchWord.length || row.name
    .toString()
    .includes(searchWord.toString()) 
)
?????.((?????) => (
  rowsPerPage > 0
  ? ?????.slice(page * rowsPerPage, page * rowsPerPage + rowsPerPage)
  : ?????
))
.map((item) => (
  <Hello />
))}
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to move it to the variable

```
let filteredRows = props.rows
  .filter((row) =>
    !searchWord.length || row.name
      .toString()
      .toLowerCase()
      .includes(searchWord.toString().toLowerCase()) 
  );

if (rowsPerPage > 0) {
  filteredRows = filteredRows.slice(page * rowsPerPage, page * rowsPerPage + rowsPerPage)
}


return filteredRows.map(item => (
  <TableRow key={item.id} hover>
    <TableCell component="th" scope="row">
      {item.id}
    </TableCell>
    <TableCell>
      {item.name}
    </TableCell>
  </TableRow>
))
```

or not recommended approach

```
{props.rows
.filter((row) =>
  !searchWord.length || row.name
    .toString()
    .toLowerCase()
    .includes(searchWord.toString().toLowerCase()) 
)
.slice(...(rowsPerPage > 0 ? [page * rowsPerPage, page * rowsPerPage + rowsPerPage] : []))
.map((item) => (
  <TableRow key={item.id} hover>
    <TableCell component="th" scope="row">
      {item.id}
    </TableCell>
    <TableCell>
      {item.name}
    </TableCell>
  </TableRow>
))}
```

Comment: Thank you for your sharing. Is it impossible to write code using only prototype?

Comment: Do you mean like chain? I've edited my answer.

Comment: Thanks to you, the problem is solved!!!